# IOException Resource not Found during Design Time in WPF

Tags: wpf, resources, ioexception, design-time

i have a problem with my WPF application during design-time. i get there error in this screenshot. it is german and means something like: IOException: the resource "x" can not be found, allthough the resource is there.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zVsS.jpg

if i clean the application after building, the error is gone. after a new build i get the error again.

it is this part of code that causes the error:

```
<Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="/Images/BachmannCEO.jpg"/>
</Grid.Background>
```

any solutions on that problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you select the image that you have added to your project and check that the build action in the properties is set to resource.

This is your mostly likely issue that it is attempting to compile it instead. Alternatively the possibility is that the image is not located relative to the source path, therefore you could try putting in the full directory path as the ImageSource and see where this gets you.

Comment: the build action of the image is set to resource.
if i put in the full directory, it works fine. but i want to be able to let the app run out of different folders, so i can not type in the directory hard.

Comment: That would suggest to me then, that there is an issue with the relative path to the image. Check the location of the image is correct relative to the application .exe file

Comment: the image is located in the project itself (see screenshot posted in my question above). after cleaning the project, it works fine...